# Since Windows 10 Creators Update HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn prints only b/w

Tags: windows-10, printing

The title says it all.

Unfortunately I cannot change in the properties window anything under "Device settings". Every option is disabled.

The test page - running from the printer properties - is also b/w.

My other printer HP OfficeJet Pro 8600 works fine.

Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: If you go to the General tab, you'll find a button saying Change advanced settings, or something with an administrative badge (UAC logo). If you click it, and the dialog reopens with admin rights, can you then change its settings?

Comment: Sure, will do. I just wanted to eliminate that you didn't already tried it, because its an obvious thing for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printer settings are greyed out by default because they require administrative privileges to alter them. You can still view the settings, just not modify them.

To make changes, you have to go to the General tab, and press the Advanced Settings (or something) with the UAC icon on it. It will ask you to confirm you want to relaunch the app with administrative privileges.

From this moment on, you can make changes in all tabs, including ports but also Device settings.

Do note, that although for this dialog, you do need admin settings, the printer preferences are usually also accessible and do not require administrative privileges.

Comment: Then I could change the device type from "Automatic" to "Color" which fixed the problem.